# Does `R` language Override variable values?

Tags: r

I'm creating a variable `dataset` and assigning a value to it like this :

```
dataset = iris
```

Now i assign a different value to the same variable like this :

```
dataset = read.csv(filename, header = FALSE)
```

Does `R` Override the previous value of dataset? Can anyone explain me how this works and can we assign more than one value to the same variable?

Comment: "can we assign more than one value to the same variable?" You could use a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `r` will override the value of the previously assigned variable (Some examples to get started can be found [here](https://www.statmethods.net/management/variables.html))

On a sidenote: In contrast to other languages, `r` uses `<-` as an assignment operator, so to make the code more readable to other users, you should consider using that instead of `=`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i read in a tutorial that both <- and = are same and we can use any? Is there any advantage besides code readability of using <-?

Comment: Yes, `r` will understand both `= ` and `<-` however, in `r` it is common practise to use `<-` as the assignment operator. It is not technically wrong, but as with other many coding practises it is considered better style. Also it is better understandable as in some cases the `->` operator exists, which assignes the left side to the right side.

Comment: And it avoid misunderstanding assignments and valuing in function calls (I.e: this works and give two variables, res and vector: `res <- paste0("blahe",vector<-c(1,2,4,4),sep=',')`)